# Slider-image getting overlapped by another div tag

Tags: html, css, image, slider

I added the menu (right-side), for that divided the first part into 2 (70-30). From that time, the image is not working properly. When I reduce the width, the image gets overlapped. Once it’s smaller than tablet width, the image vanishes. In mobile or tablet, I want the image to display first without getting cut and then to display the right-one menu (below the image, in mobile and tablet).

```html
<section class="no-padding main-slider height-100 mobile-height wow fadeIn" style="display:block;">
            
   <div class="swiper-full-screen swiper-container height-100 black-move mobile-height" id="section01" style="width:70%;float:left;z-index:1;">
                <div class="swiper-wrapper" style="margin-top:66px;display:inline-block;">
                    
                    <!-- start slider item -->
                    <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url('./images/slide01.jpg');">
                    </div>
                    <!-- end slider item -->
                    <!-- start slider item -->
                    <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url('./images/slide2.jpg');">
                    </div>
                    </div>
    <!-- start slider pagination -->
                <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
                <div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-black-highlight display-none"></div>
                <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-black-highlight display-none"></div>
                <!-- end slider pagination -->
            </div>
            <div class="mobile-height" id="section02" style="display:inline-block;float:right;width:400px;">
    <div class="container01" style="margin-top:66px;margin-bottom:12px;">
  
      <!-- testimonials begin -->
      <div class="tsl">
        <ul class="tsl-list" style="background-color:#D32F2F;">
       <li class="tsl-item" style="color:white;">
         <article class="tsl-content" style="padding-top:20px;">
         <p>Migrane</p>
        </article>
       </li>
       <li class="tsl-item" style="color:white;">
         <article class="tsl-content" style="padding-top:20px;">
         <p>Sinus</p>
        </article>
       </li>
       <li class="tsl-item" style="color:white;">
         <article class="tsl-content" style="padding-top:20px;">
         <p>Asthama</p>
        </article>
       </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
       
      <!-- testimonials end -->
      
    </div>
        </div>
        </section>
```

**Desktop Width:**

[image: Desktop Width]

**Tablet or iPad Width:**

[image: Tablet or Ipad Width]

**Mobile Width:**

[image: Mobile Width]

Comment: Please provide your code.

Answer (score 1):

A quick way of achieving this is setting up inline-blocks for both DIVs. Although using something like Bootstrap could help you out immensely. You should include the current code and styles so that we can help out more

```
<style>
    .container {
     display:block;
    }

    .image-container {
     display:inline-block;
    }
    .menu-container {
     display:inline-block;
     float:right;
     width:400px
    }
</style>



<div class="container">
    <div class="image-container">
        image
    </div>
    <div class="menu-container">
        menu
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: its not working properly. image is not even displaying.

Comment: I saw your code..  there is nothing giving width to the image DIV.. What I would do is get Bootstrap and use the swiper slide inside a  row column and the menu in a smaller column to the right..